Azure Managed Grafana - how to embed a graph on an WebApp
I am creating a web application to display a graph created in Azure managed Grafana. I am trying to achieve this using the share->Embed option on the graph panel.
It has been challenging. I have searched through lots of forums and looked for tutorials on youtube and I haven't found anything that gives me a definitive answer, unfortunately.
I managed to embed a graph on an app using Grafana installed standalone on a PC.
To do this, in grafana.ini
[auth.anonymous]
enabled = true

allow_embedding=true

using Grafana installed on Docker, I found that you can use the -e option,
-e "GF_SECURITY_ALLOW_EMBEDDING=true"
to enable this (but I am not interested in this implementation).
With Azure Managed Grafana, grafana.ini does not appear visible and accessible.
Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Are you looking the approach only with the Grafana or any Azure related monitoring? @KaiT

Hi, @Jahnavi, we are only looking for a solution for this particular case.

Have you checked this Githib issue by any chance! @KaiT

Thank you @Jahnavi, I have just checked it now, but unfortunately, these options do not appear to be modifiable in case of Azure managed Grafana :(

It's a question for Azure support.

@ClémentDuveau We have been in touch with them. I will update this post once I have got an answer.

We finally received an answer from the Azure support. They confirmed that this usage is not currently supported in Azure Managed Grafana.
